# How Can I add multiple unique values inside a document under collections in the Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add multiple roll number(unique) inside a document field inside a collection in a Cloud Firestore. How can I achieve it plus I wanted to restrict the user to not enter more than 5 values. Can I get some help out here?

Groupformation_fragment.java

```
    public class groupformation_fragment extends Fragment {

private Button submit;
EditText ET1,ET2,ET3,ET4,ET5;
private FirebaseFirestore mfirestore;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_groupformation,null);

   ET1=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.ET1);
    ET2=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.ET2);
    ET3=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.ET3);
    ET4=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.ET4);
    ET5=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.ET5);
    submit=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submit);
   return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String roll1=ET1.getText().toString();
            String roll2=ET2.getText().toString();
            String roll3=ET3.getText().toString();
            String roll4=ET4.getText().toString();
            String roll5=ET5.getText().toString();

            Map<String,String> usermap= new HashMap<>();
            usermap.put("Student1",roll1);
            usermap.put("Student2",roll2);
            usermap.put("Student3",roll3);
            usermap.put("Student4",roll4);
            usermap.put("Student5",roll5);

            mfirestore.collection("group").add(usermap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Group Has been Registered For The Project", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               String error=e.getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error :"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });




        }
    });


}
```

}

fragement_groupformation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"   />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"  />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:text="Submit"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat Error shown

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kiit.projectmanager, PID: 7163
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.kiit.projectmanager.groupformation_fragment$1.onClick(groupformation_fragment.java:62)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7163 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: i am unable to find the logic for it .please if someone can guide me as i am a begginer in it.

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: i am not able to figure out how to add those unique roll numbers ."mfirestore.collection("group").document(get).addOnSuccessListener" i am not able to get the document reference

Comment: @AlexMamo  could you tell me the solution for it how can i get this done

Comment: Is your `onSuccess` even triggered? Is your toast message displayed?

Comment: nope it crashes ..the problem  i am not able to figure out to put multiple vaues in it

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: mfirestore.collection("group").add(usermap).addOnSuccessListener

Comment: @AlexMamo please help me i have to submit this project by time i don't know what  wrong i did however i updated the code and the error please look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beeing a `NullPointerException`, it means that you haven't initialized the `mfirestore` object anywhere in your code. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
private FirebaseFirestore mfirestore;
```

to

```
private FirebaseFirestore mfirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

Comment: thanks worked for me can you guide how can i store  those number uniquely??a method or a video that you can suggest

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) How to store unique ids, I suggest you use CollectionReference's [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#add(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method or CollectionReference's [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#document()) method without passing any parameters.

Comment: Hey i  am not able to figure out how to do it ? can you please explain with the example...that too in my case it would be really helpful else you can give you own eg: too @alex

Comment: This question is not related to the first one. In order to follow the rules of this community, please post another fresh question, so me and other Firebase developers can help you.